# How to map a concrete class to another type without nested ternary?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a class, say, `BasicModal` and one type describing `BasicModal`'s configurations, `type BasicModalConfig = {}` for instance, and I also have a function, that takes the class and its settings a parameters, let's assume its signature is `function openModal(component, configs);`. The goal is to infer the component's type (or class name if useful/possible) and use it in `config`'s type as a **type parameter** and set the configurations value accordingly, in other words, mapped types, but without the nested ternary madness.

Example of the desired result:

```js
// This works

interface BasicModalConfig {
  autoClose: boolean;
};

class BasicModal {}

// This would get out of hand very fast
type TypeResolver<K> = K extends BasicModal ? BasicModalConfig : never;

function openModal<T>(component: T, configs: TypeResolver<T>) {}

openModal(BasicModal, {
  autoClose: true // this should give me hints/autocompletion
});

// This doesn't work
interface Resolver {
  BasicModal: BasicModalConfig;
}
//or (doesn't compile)
//type Resolver = {
//  [x: typeof BasicModal]: BasicModalConfig;
//};

function openModal2<T>(component: T, configs: Resolver[T extends keyof Resolver ? T : never]
) {}

openModal2(BasicModal, {
  autoClose: true // this should give me hints/autocompletion, but config is "never"
});
```

I searched for something like "`nameof`" from C#, in Typescript repository, to use it as a key value, but it's still in discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579

As of typescript version 4.6, is it possible to even achieve this?

Here's a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-aj-UCA-DA0Hg5yQhq4CaqaSTXgM0CIgBEhuIqZhuiAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solutions, depending on how coupled you want the config and model to be.

You could add a field to the model that is the same type as  the config and use conditional types to extract the config type:

```
type TypeResolver<K> = K extends { __config?: infer U } ? U : never;

function openModal<T>(component: T, configs: TypeResolver<T>) {}

openModal(BasicModal, {
  autoClose: true // this should give me hints/autocompletion
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAoaA7ALgKYoBmAhgMYGgBCps05AskgCakA2AwkjsdAOagA3plChSAVzxJO7JLAIAuUACMkSdgVI4A3JgC+ezOXZ14tek1Ydho0LDyk8DUAH1X5Hn34B+ZRYZmNi4vAQNMTDwATwAHKnBYggAlAlgNADciAB4AaQA+UABeUBzQAgAPQhwWeCE3D1DfZVxiIlAAVVB9UB8O0GUcAkyUI2IJHHJnHlAkOJwgjizwPIAKTwBbGJ4CfGVwABpQT14BWD3ElLT2YaW8gEphfQjZnYX2FYCrYMORMUlpWTyJSgPAoCRUEAgmDwWCQJASdgsUD8aCZUDrKgwfCwYD-JAbGKaKY4Ax3PRAA)

You could also have a mapping between types, but since as you point out there is no `nameof` in TS, you can use an object type for the value and extract from  the values in the interface:

```
type TypeResolver<K> = Extract<TypeResolverMap[keyof TypeResolverMap], { model: K }>['config']

interface TypeResolverMap {
  BasicModal: { model: typeof BasicModal; config: BasicModalConfig }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAoaA7ALgKYoBmAhgMYGgBCps05AskgCakA2AwkjsdAOagA3plChSAVzxJO7JLAIAuUACMkSdgVI4A3JgC+ezOXZ14tek1YdhBzJjwBPAA5VwLggCUCsDQDciAB4AaQA+UABeUABRAA88FAo8QPdXb192AJRGUmcAbTQCRyRiCA90-yIc5wBdABphUABbVgJ2ZWDQfVC8gHJyHj5+Xpr7XEISCjdyn0rs3NsxCwZmNnbGlpY25SdXEpo6Fet2HVAB3gFlZas17gvBfTtMYgkccjxoHlAkVxxVjhSoQAFAMms4eAR8MpwA1zkNYNCZhksoCAJTCR6YH6Q-7sIHXXENERiSTSWTyJSgBISKggKkweCwSBICTsFigfjQALNKgwfCwYCkpCg5yaD48AyovRAA)

Or you could use a tuple for the mapping instead of an interface (although interfaces are open ended so you can add models from other files):

```
type TypeResolver<K> = Extract<TypeResolverMap[number], [K, any]>[1]

type TypeResolverMap = [
  [typeof BasicModal, BasicModalConfig]
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAoaA7ALgKYoBmAhgMYGgBCps05AskgCakA2AwkjsdAOagA3plChSAVzxJO7JLAIAuUACMkSdgVI4A3JgC+ezOXZ14tek1YdhBzJjwBPAA5VwLggCUCsDQDciAB4AaQA+UABeUABRAA88FAo8QPdXb192AJRGUmcAbRwJAFsVIgBdABpQPOCq7Ucy0LyARjL7J1cID3T-IhznSOrRao6CJGIaOgZmNnYqi2nrLh4+fja2zGIJHHI8aB5QJFccGY4U0IAKciQi5x4CfGVwKuveAVgn7p9elHOASmE+nsRwep3YFwWVlmVREYkk0lk8iUoASEioIBRMHgsEgSAk7BYoH40ACoCKVBg+FgwHhSGut00ex4Bj+eiAA)

Or a mix between an interface and tuples:

```
type TypeResolver<K> = Extract<TypeResolverMap[keyof TypeResolverMap], [K, any]>[1]

interface TypeResolverMap {
  BasicModal: [typeof BasicModal, BasicModalConfig]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAoaA7ALgKYoBmAhgMYGgBCps05AskgCakA2AwkjsdAOagA3plChSAVzxJO7JLAIAuUACMkSdgVI4A3JgC+ezOXZ14tek1YdhBzJjwBPAA5VwLggCUCsDQDciAB4AaQA+UABeUABRAA88FAo8QPdXb192AJRGUmcAbTQCRyRiCA90-yIc5wBdABpQPOCG7Uca0LyARhr7XEISCjdyn0rs3NsxCwZmNnZlPKdXEpo6aet2BqmrWe5eAR79e2IJHHI8aB5QJFccGY4U0IAKciQAW2ceAnxlcAaXvf4sB+wwyWQeAEphIdMNcvnd2I8tvCGiIxJJpLJ5EpQAkJFQQDiYPBYJAkBJ2CxQPxoAFQK8qDB8LBgOikC93ppzjwDOC9EA)

Comment: Interesting solution. I like your 2nd and 3rd solutions better, though, when I add another class and interface, to the resolver, it results in a union, not a 1:1 mapping. I can't send an example because the link is too large. :/

Comment: I any case, I'll consider as an answer.

Comment: Well, I guess your first solution answers my question. But I'm not comfortable adding a property to the class, and unfortunately I couldn't get your other solutions to work properly, i. e. without yielding a union of the classes. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDPKjN)

Comment: As you can (hopefully) see in the playground, it always resolves to a union of the two interfaces ("configs: BasicModalConfig | ComplexModalConfig").

Comment: @RickStanley The problem is that the two classes are basically the same type. Add any prop with a different name between the two classes or a private prop and you will get the correct types: https://tsplay.dev/mZr2Dm